# Does different database system implementations (e.g. MySQL, and Microsoft SQL Server) affect `DataSource` and `DriverManager` differently?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Here is some comparison of using `DataSource` and using `DriverManager` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19674833/1224441

> With JDBC, we can use an abstracted class, such as
>   `java.sql.DataSource`, which defines a database. However,
>   **the MySQL DataSource and a Microsoft SQL DataSource are different
>   implementations. JDBC doesn't know which one you want to use.**
>
> So you use DriverManager to specify to JDBC that you want to use the
>   MySQL implementation, and you load that driver's class.
>    **Say that later on you switch to Microsoft SQL. Now, all you have to do
>   is change the DriverManager to load the Microsoft SQL driver's class,
>   and all of your code that uses the abstract `java.sql`
>   classes will still work.**

I found some examples of using `DataSource` and using `DriverManager` at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/jeetutorials/datasource/

But I don't see how different implementations (e.g.  implementations by MySQL, and Microsoft SQL Server) would affect `DataSource` and `DriverManager` differently. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you acces you database with JDBC, you will handle `java.sql.Connection`, `java.sql.Resultset`... which are interfaces. You will actually use implementations that are specific to your database.

That way most of the code you wrote for one database can be used with another one and you don't have to learn a new API each time you need to access a new DB.

You need to specify first which implementations you need which are provided by the JDBC driver. You can do it with the *old school* `DriverManager` or with the now preferred `DataSource`.

### DriverManager

The [`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) is a concrete class. It isn't specific to any database. In summary it is just the place where you register your driver so you can get later all the specific implementations you need. It isn't specific by itself but it provides all the specific stuff you need.

Here is an excerpt from the example you mentioned with some of my comments.

```
final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books";

//This line returns the Class of the Jdbc drive
//It will not be used but doing this will allow 
//static initializations where it will register
//the driver to the DriverManager
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//Here you get your connection implmentation
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

//MySQL specific Statement
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
//MySQL specific ResultSet
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books");
```

The "trap" here is that the registration of the driver (to the DriverManager) is done during the static init done when you call the the `Class.forName` method.

For your information, [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.33/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java) is the piece of code in `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` doing the the driver registration in the init:

```
public class Driver extends NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
    //
    // Register ourselves with the DriverManager
    //
    static {
        try {
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
        } catch (SQLException E) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
        }
    }
```

### DataSource

Using [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) is more suitable for external configuration. `DataSource` is an `interface` and the implementation depends directly on the database.

In your example, the Driver implementation is specified in the `web.xml` file.

First we define the driver to be able to find it with [JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/index.html)

```
<database>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/mysql</jndi-name>
  <driver>
    <type>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource</type>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books</url>
    <user>root</user>
    <password></password>
  </driver>
<database>
```

And then we pass the reference to the servlet :

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>datasource</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.zetcode.DataSourceExample</servlet-class>
 <init>
    <data-source>${jndi:lookup('jdbc/mysql')}</data-source>
 </init>
</servlet>
```

That way, you had not to write any specific line of code. If you change your database, (in theory) you just have to change your configuration. Not the code.

### Important notes

1. As Kayaman mentioned in the comments calling `Class.forName` is no longer needed since Java 6. All you need is having the driver in your classpath.
2. As a reminder using `DriverManager` is not recommended anymore. See this excerpt from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> **NOTE**: The [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface, new in the JDBC 2.0 API, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a DataSource object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source.

Comment: Thanks. How about the other way by `DataSource`?

Comment: The `Class.forName()` hasn't really been needed for years.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry but the OP started from an example using this and I thought it was interesting to explain its use in this context.

Comment: Yup, I just commented that it's unnecessary. It's a great example of cargo cult programming.

Comment: Your answer so far addresses only the way of using `DriverManager`. How differently do different database systems affect the other way by `DataSource`?

Comment: @Ethan Sorry, I was a bit busy. I will edit my answer soon

Comment: Thanks. Does changing implementation (e.g. from MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server)   affect DataSource but not DriverManager? Or how differently does the change affect both?

Comment: @Ethan Sorry, I realize that I didn't really answer to your question. See my edited answer. Just to summarize: the `DataSource` is an interface and the implementations are specific to the DB while the old `DriverManager` references the specific implementations.

Comment: Thanks. Does the way by `DataSource` depend on specific driver and database system, because the specific driver and database system are specified in the web.xml? Does the way by `DriverManager` not depend on specific driver and databas system, because the specific driver and database system are specified as arguments to the methods of `DriverManager` and `Class`?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, at least this is how I understood your question. (I am not sure to understand what blocks you.)  `DataSource` implementation depends on specific DB system because it must be provided by DB driver. (Using web.xml is an option.) `DriverProvider` is already in the JDK.